# STM32 - ESP8266 -GET Request

Tags: stm32, esp8266

I'm using STM32 with ESp8266 using latest AT Command Firmware V2
Also i'm including https://github.com/nimaltd/ESP8266
Which helps parse at commands

I can connect to my router access point and my local tcp server but when sending GET requests i receive nothing on my local

```
    const char* host = "192.168.1.9";

      while(!Wifi_TcpIp_StartTcpConnection(0,host,3437,10)){
          char buffer[] = "Unable to connect to TCP Backend\r\n";
                        HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart1,buffer,sizeof(buffer),HAL_MAX_DELAY);

      };

uint8_t  req   ="GET /opaaa HTTP/1.1\r\n";          Wifi_TcpIp_SendDataTcp(0,sizeof(req),&req); //success but i receive nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the TCP communication works properly (you can connect to the server, send and receive data) and that the host you connect to serves HTTP on that port, the issue I can see with your request is that you're missing an additional CRLF at the end, like so:

```
char *req = "GET /opaaa HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n";
Wifi_TcpIp_SendDataTcp(0, strlen(req), (uint8_t*)req);
```

This signifies the end of HTTP headers that you're sending. In your original case, the server may still be waiting for more headers and therefore holding with sending the response back to you.

I also suggest to clean up the sending code, one way of which I've pasted above - you were assigning a string to a single byte `uint8_t` variable.

Comment: Thats works, thanks alot, any ideas how to add a header to the request ? for example a token param in the header ?

Comment: You add HTTP headers after first CRLF (`\r\n`) and before the double CRLF at the end or in other words - before the empty header. For example: `GET /opaaa HTTP/1.1\r\nToken: abc\r\nSome-Other-Header: xyz\r\n\r\n`.